# Webpack compilation, local Module not found: Error: Can't resolve

Tags: nativescript

I modified a plugin and added it in my project's file system. So in my package.json I have : `"some-module": "file:modules/some-module"`.

It works fine on my machine (Windows), but not on our build server (Linux CentOS), which fails during webpack compilation with error : `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'some-module'`.

The build server does clean the workspace before build, and after the failed build the plugin does exist in 'node_modules' folder of the workspace.

What could cause this error if the plugin does exists ?

EDIT : I tried on another linux machine (CentOS) and build failed for same error.

EDIT2 : I changed the local `file:` reference in my package.json file to a .tar.gz git `URL`. The error is now :

`ERROR in ../node_modules/nativescript-pdfview-ng/pdfview-ng.ts
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: /root/myProject/node_modules/nativescript-pdfview-ng/pdfview-ng.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format ([link][1]).
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/root/myProject/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:719:23)
    at plugin.done.then (/root/myProject/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:41:31)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)`

Comment: You mean the webpack build works on your machine but not just on the build server? Can you disclose which module is creating the problem?

Comment: Yes that is right. The original module is nativescript-pdfview-ng

Comment: Are you using Angular?

Comment: yes nativescript-angular 6.1.0, nativescript 5.1.1 & tns-cores-modules 4.2.1

Comment: Do you have an identical configuration locally and on the CI server?

Comment: as close as I could get. I mean android sdk is platform dependent for exemple. But versions numbers are the same on each sides yes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using NativeScript 5.x?

If so, make sure to prefix the plugin with "nativescript-", since {N} 5.x the module resolution seems to have changed with regards to Webpack'ed build.

Comment: Yes & good to know, but my plugin does start with "nativescript-"